# Можно послать Ctrl+z во все открытые терминалы (приостановить выполнение) скриптом?

Tags: ubuntu, консоль

Можно послать Ctrl+z во все открытые терминалы на ubuntu (приостановить выполнение) одной командой (скриптом)? 
То же вопрос, но уже во все работающие screen ?
Если есть способ, то как потом послать `fg` ?
спасибо

Comment: `$ for l in /proc/*/fd/1; do if readlink -f $l | grep -q /dev/pts; then p=${l#/proc/}; echo ${p%%/*}; fi; done` вернёт список процессов, у которых *stdin* связан с `/dev/pts/*`. можно им всем отправить сигнал `ttin` (`$ man 7 signal`) — это аналог нажатия `^z`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, так можно и непричастных прихватить. Может лучше искать те, у кого родитель эмулятор терминала?

Comment: @avp, это был пример. поискать всех потомков рекурсивно тоже можно, но поля книги слишком узки для этого.

Comment: @avp, но автора вопроса явно интересует совсем не это, а какая-нибудь приблуда типа xdotool.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а причем тут рекурсия? Shell посылает по ^Z сигнал для `process group` с тем же id, что у группы управляющего терминала. Поэтому я и рекомендовал такой поиск. Впрочем, усыпить  их таким скриптом, конечно можно, а вот эмулировать `fg` без участия Shell наверное не получится (по крайней мере я не понимаю, как это сделать)